# Set a counter sql

Tags: sql, counter

I am not an expert in sql and I am trying to find a solution on the below problem.

I have the following data

```
test   -    test1 
31477831 -  a1 
31477831 -  a0 
31477831 -  a1 
31477831 -  a0 
31477831 -  a0 
31477832 -  a0 
31477832 -  a0 
31477832 -  a1
```

And I need to set a counter as below:

```
test -     test1    - counter
31477831 -  a1      - 0
31477831 -  a0      - 1
31477831 -  a1      - 2
31477831 -  a0      - 3
31477831 -  a0      - 3
31477832 -  a0      - 0
31477832 -  a0      - 0
31477832 -  a1      - 1
```

When the test filed change need to start from 0 when test1 field change need to increment by 1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What rdbms? MySQL, SQL Server, etc.

Comment: basically you need a rank, but it depends on the rdbms

Comment: I don't see by what rule you apply the counter. Record 31477831|a0 for instance apperas thrice in the table, but one time you give it the counter 1 and twice you give it the counter 3. You are aware that there is no inherent order of records in a table, aren't you? There are just three identical records which you are trying to treat as if there were different. Please elaborate what you are trying to do exactly. Is there maybe another column in the table giving some order to the records (a date, an ID, whatever) you haven't shown us?

Comment: Sorry MS SQL server

Answer (score 1):

You could use analytic functions (SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL 8.0+/PostgreSQL/...):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN LAG(test1) OVER(PARTITION BY test ORDER BY id) <> test1 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END l
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *, SUM(l) OVER(PARTITION BY test ORDER BY id) AS counter
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bd52e4829ca4d5a440266106e3ed7627)**

For stable sort you need some kind of id/timestamp column.